# Formula Field Discrepancy

Tags: formula

can someone explain why the formula below has no syntax error: 
 **Days to Close (Number) =  CloseDate  -  TODAY()**

but the one below has a syntax error:
**Days Since Last Update (Number) = LastModifiedDate - TODAY()**

They are both subtracting date fields but I'm getting the following  error from the second one: 
**Error: Incorrect parameter type for operator '-'. Expected Number, DateTime, received Date**

Does't make any sense to me. Can someone make sense of this. Thanks

Comment: I hope  you are talking about the closedate field on opportunity.CloseDate is a field of type "Date" whereas "LastModifiedDate" is a field of type "Date Time"."Today()" function returns value of type "Date".So the lastmodifieddate should be converted to date inorder to subtract it from today() as per the below answer https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=formula_using_date_datetime.htm&language=en_US&type=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LastModifiedDate` is a DateTime field

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/system_fields.htm

Use `DATEVALUE(LastModifiedDate) - TODAY()`